# Django query laziness, too many results, memory insufficiency

Tags: django

I have an application that visaulises users' excel data. They are uploading their excel data and the app inserts data to our 'postgresql' database.

We are testing our application with a query that gets 20.000 results. But our server with 256 mb memory gives memory insufficient error. ( single user, single query )

I have read about optimizing queries on django web. But i have still some questions:

```
#datapoints are related with channels i know that here django does not touch to db
datapoints = Datapoint.objects.filter(channel__id = c.id).order_by('time')
datapointSets.append({'channelName':c.name, 'datapoints':datapoints})

#in my template:
# i guess this is the first time django touches database gets 20.000 results and do caching for other calls
{% for datapointSet in datapointSets %}
        {% for dp in datapointSet.datapoints %}
{{ dp.value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

# i again loop in the results for a reason (in the same template again)
{% for datapointSet in datapointSets %}
        {% for dp in datapointSet.datapoints %}
{{ dp.value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here in the template when looping in the result for the second time does django touch to the database and cache again?  ( do i need to use 'with' template tag preventing extra query )

In a situation like this is it better to use iterator()?

Comment: Either increase the memory on your server, add a swap partition/file or use pagination. Doesn't matter how efficient your query is, it's apparent that 256MB isn't enough to hold your application as it's.

Comment: It may sound impolite, but is your settings.DEBUG=False?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is only queried once. That is the whole point of the queryset cache.

If you only need the `value` attribute, you could save memory by only getting that field with `values('value')` in the original query.

Comment: No i need all fields . SSohow can i find the memory problem. Do i need to use iterator ? Because say a hundred people do the query... or is raw sql query a solution